# jquery .serialize()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't get jquery .serialize() to work correctly. I have a form of dynamically generated checkboxes. The page wont submit the check boxes. Can you please tell me where I went wrong.

```
     $('#prof_take_attendance_submit').live("click",function(){
            var current_class = $('#class_choice :selected').attr('name');// GET CURRENT CLASS
            var prof_id = $('#prof_id').text();// GET PROFFESSOR ID NUMBER
                $("#prof_take_attendance_form").trigger('submit',function(){
                var query_string = $(this).serialize(); 
                        });

                $("#take_attendance_prof")// CALL TO FORM  
                .html(ajax_load)  
                .load(loadUrl, "form_being_submitted=prof_save_attendance&class="+current_class+"&prof_id="+prof_id+""+query_string);
        $('#take_attendance_prof').fadeIn(200);

     });
```

Comment: Define `properly`. We don't know what actually happens on your page

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. I'm having troubles selecting the dynamically generated checked checkboxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on assumption that `$('#prof_take_attendance_submit')` is a submit button you are trying to serialize just the button

Try:

```
   var query_string = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
```

Without more info about form is pretty hard to see what elese may not be working

EDIT: Get rid of trigger, bind submit to form not button

```
 $("#prof_take_attendance_form").live('submit', function(){
      var query_string = $(this).serialize(); 

       /* other code and ajax*/

 })
```

Comment: code is very strange having trigger submit and then you ajax right after...are you submitting 2 places?

Comment: This is completly unneeded traversing.

Comment: @charlietfl No I was just trying to get it to work. I thought that force submiting it would work.

Comment: no..is not good idea...should remove all that , and instead of binding submit to the button, bind submit to form itself right from start...added extra code to show binding submit to form

Answer (score 2):

Serialize the form not the button

```
$("#prof_take_attendance_form").serialize();
```

Comment: @Cjueden, I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/C4pd5/1/) just to prove it to you